# `std::iota_view` is slow when given different types of value and bound?

Tags: c++, c++20, binary-search, std-ranges, iota

I was solving a programming task where we wanted to find a smallest integer not satisfying a given (monotone) property. This can be achieved via binary search. Using C++20, I decided to use `std::partition_point` together with `std::iota_view`. I had several types mixed up and my code was very slow for some reason. My code (simplified):

```
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <climits>
bool monotone(int n)
{
    return n <= 1000000000;
}

long long MAX = INT_MAX; //weird?
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << *ranges::partition_point(ranges::iota_view(1,MAX), monotone) << endl;
}
```

by looking closer, it is weird that `MAX` is of type `long long` while it could be int. Running this on my machine yields a running time of approximately 12 seconds, which is too much, it should be logarithmic in `MAX`. I noticed that if i changed `ranges::iota_view(1,MAX)` to `ranges::iota_view(1ll, MAX)` or `ranges::iota_view(1,(int)MAX)` the code suddenly began to "work" fast as intended (completed in few milliseconds).

In both scenarios, i measured that the function `monotone` was called exactly `31` times (in this case), so the time complexity regarding number of calls of the predicate is ok.

Can someone explain to me what is going on under the hood and why mixing up types in the `iota_view` produced such slow code?

Edit: the issue seems to lie in calling `ranges::distance` inside `ranges::partition_point` which specializes itself to the variant where it computes distance of `std::iota_view<int,long long>::_Iterator` and `std::iota_view<int,long long>::_Sentinel` in linear time. Instead, when giving `iota_view` the same two types (either two `int`s or two `long long`s), the specialization chooses to compute distance between `std::iota_view<int,int>::_Iterator` and `std::iota_view<int,int>::_Iterator` which falls into the specialization where it is computed in O(1) simply as difference of two ints.

However, why such specialization occurs is still a mystery to me and would like a detailed explanation on why it behaves like this.

Comment: *Running this on my machine yields a running time of approximately 12 seconds,* -- Speed of a C++ program should be accompanied by the compiler and compiler options used to build the program.  The most important of these options are the optimizations settings used.  If you are timing an unoptimized or "debug" build, then the timings you are reporting are meaningless.

Comment: Question about performance must include all necessary details like **compiler used(with version), optimization used, platform, command(s) used to build the program, exact code used** etc

Comment: It could be all the conversions from `int` to `long long` that makes it take time.

Comment: This is not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Where are all the `#include`'s?

Comment: This doesn't have to do anything with compiler. The running time has only informative character. The issues it rather which templates and concepts gets specialized during instantiation of all the template bloat inside the functions I am calling. But I am using gcc 11.4.

Comment: *"yields a running time of approximately 12 seconds..."* **We need exact code used to measure performance.**

Comment: _"I am using gcc 11.4"_ - Ok, with the added headers, it does compile for me too. I'm using gcc 13.2.1 and it takes 0.004s to run for me. Did you use an optimized build? How did you compile this?

Comment: *"ssues it rather which templates and concepts..."* Are you talking about compile time performance or runtime?

Comment: I am talking about runtime performance and the 31 was referring to the fact that the function `monotone` given in the parameter is called the same amount of times in both variants (`int` and `long long`, `int` and `int`) so the issue is not that the function `ranges::partition_point` would behave differently.

Comment: @MichalDvořák Did you make an optimized build? Exactly how did you compile this?

Comment: By the way I updated the post with some more observations about what is going on.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes because there is no hard evidence for what OP's saying/claiming as they've not provided enough information.

Comment: @MichalDvořák Did you make an optimized build? Exactly how did you compile this? If I use `-O3` it takes 0.004 seconds to run. With no optimization it takes 21 seconds.

Comment: @TedLyngmo to be fair, with optimizations `-O2` the optimizer seemed to remove the bottleneck (which was really in the linear complexity in `ranges::distance` function.

However, I am not looking to make my code run faster. I can write my own `partition_point` or code the logic myself and I can see that it is supposed to run fast because I can see that there is indeed log(n) iterations etc. . I am more interested in what got instantiated inside the functions and why is it slow even "without optimisations". I know that the statement is vague, however I don't know how to explain it better ...

Comment: @MichalDvořák Ok, then that's it. Measuring performance in unoptimized builds usually doesn't give anything valuable. My guess is that it has to do a lot of `int` to `long long` conversions in the unoptimized build. I can't verify it now though.

Comment: Turns out my answer was completely wrong, see edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `iota_view` receives different argument types, `.end()` returns a *sentinel* instead of an iterator.

A sentinel is a type that's `==`-comparable with an iterator, and optionally subtractible from it (the latter makes it a [sized sentinel](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/sized_sentinel_for)).

If it happens to not be subtractible, `ranges::partition_point` can't know the range size in advance, and has to increment the iterator step by step (almost as if it wasn't random-access).

For some reason, for `iota_view<A,B>` this sentinel is [specified](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view/sentinel#Non-member_functions) to overload `-` only if `std::sized_sentinel_for<B, A> == true`, which is false, because neither is an iterator in this case (`int` and `long long`).